# Ionic 2 - how to change tab name

Tags: ionic2

After you create new tabs template with Ionic 2, and you want to replace one of the tab names to something else, for example settings, is there a easy/fast way to do this without changing all instances and the files names, or creating new tab and to delete the other?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the text that appears as the tab link, then go to src/pages/tabs/tabs.html and in that file change the `tabTitle` to whatever text you would like to display.

For example `<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Settings" tabIcon="list"></ion-tab>`

Comment: For example, when you create new tabs template and you want to change the 'about' tab to 'settings'. You can change the title but the files still will be called 'about'.